# p:selectOneMenu "rejects" selection the first time it is used

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have this strange situation, the very first time i access the page containing this code, whenever i select any value, the control flashes from the selected value and returns to the first value - Listener not called if present -. From that point on, things works fine.

The values are the letters a-z plus an empty not null string.

Ran it with tomcat 7

t hanks

**launcher.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


    <h:body >
        <ui:composition template="/paginas/comun/layout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="contenido">            
                <ui:insert name="funcionalidad" >
                    <ui:include src="_launcher.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>     
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>    
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**_launcher.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:form id="form">   
    <p:panel 
    header="faster than the speed of love"
    id="ulricso">

    <p:selectOneMenu                   
            value="#{direccionPuntualBean.letra11}">
                <p:ajax
                process="@all"
                update="@form"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{direccionPuntualBean.letras}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>                      
    </p:panel>      

    </h:form>           

</html>
```

**bean excerpt**

```
public List<String> getLetras() {
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        ls.add("");
        for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            ls.add(new String("" + (char)i));
        }
        return ls;
    }
```

Comment: That code works fine when put in a completely blank page with just a `<h:form>` which is opened by just a GET request. Does that really represent your case? Or is in your real code the form containing that component being conditionally rendered by an ajax POST request from another form beforehand?

Comment: thanks balus, i edited my question to include full xhtml's code. as you can see there is no conditional rendering.

Comment: What's that XML prolog, doctype and `<html>` doing in your include? Now you end up with nested `<html>` elements like so `<?xml?><!DOCTYPE..><html><body><?xml?><!DOCTYPE..><html><form>` resulting in syntactically invalid HTML (rightclick and *View Soruce* in browser .. check in http://validator.w3.org to validate HTML). That might as well be the cause of your problem. Browser behavior is unspecified as to invalid HTML.

Comment: And also you are generating array in getter, which may not be the source of problem, but is expensive. Getter methods are called multiple times during JSF lifecycle.

Comment: ah ok. sure i will move the array generation to the bean's constructor.

Comment: @BalusC as you say, the generated html contains various html tags. however if i remove the prolog and html tags from _launcher.xhtml i end up with [ javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: the prefix "h" for element "h:form"  is  not bound ] the confusing thing is that in these tutorials: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/facelets-454361.html and http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/ both use html tags and xml prologs in all their pages.